# Chinese aphorism about smile

Tags: translation, literary-chinese

There are many aphorisms in ancient chinese literature. One of them goes somewhat like: 
"An angry fist does not hit a smiling face" 
Please help me to translate it into Chinese correctly. Google translated it like that:
愤怒的小拳头不会撞上的一个笑脸

Comment: you mean 伸手不打笑脸人?

Comment: I think it is the right variant. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's [伸手不打笑脸人](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BC%B8%E6%89%8B%E4%B8%8D%E6%89%93%E7%AC%91%E8%84%B8%E4%BA%BA) or [举手不打笑脸人](https://www.pmume.com/yanyu/nyrbg.shtml).

> 意思是当你举起手要打有错的对方时，对方已经在向你赔着笑脸认错了，这时候你就不忍心，也不好意思再去打人家了。
>
> 谓不欺侮老实善良的人。或谓要宽恕已知理亏而以礼待人的人。也说“举手不打笑脸人”。